# Cardinality of the set of bijective functions from real numbers to real numbers

Tags: set-theory

I know that functions from real numbers to real numbers form a set

$F = \{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \}$

with cardinality

$|F| = 2^\mathfrak{c}$

Question: what about the set of bijections

$\Pi = \{\pi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} | \; \pi \;\text{bijective} \} \subset F$

and its cardinality?

Is it reasonable use a diagonal argument?

Idea:

Assume

$|\Pi| = \mathfrak{c}$

Then

$\forall \pi \in \Pi: \exists r \in \mathbb{R} \;\text{such that} \; \pi = f(r,.)$

Does this idea make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed $Π⊆F$, so it is sufficient to show that $|Π|≥|\mathcal P(\Bbb R)|$, but $|\mathcal P(\Bbb R)|=|\{x⊆\Bbb R\mid |x|>1\}|$.

Now given $X \in\{x⊆\Bbb R\mid |x|>1\}$, let $f_X:X\to X$ be a bijection without fixed points, and define $f'_X:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be $f_X'(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in X$ and $f'_X(x)=x$ otherwise, this is a bijection, and given $X,Y∈\{x⊆\Bbb R\mid |x|>1\}$, if $X\ne Y$ then $f'_X\ne f'_Y$, so the function $g:\{x⊆\Bbb R\mid |x|>1\}→Π$ given by $g(z)=f'_z$ is injective.